# How to run a Conexant driver application flow.exe in background

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, sound-card

I have HP EliteBook 840 G5 with Conexant sound card. When the computer starts driver application `flow.exe` automatically starts.

Is there any way to run this app in background?

[image: Conexant Driver Applicatin]

[image: App in Task Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Find **flowsetup.ini**(ex: C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\Flow)
2. Find a uninstall string:"Setup.exe -U -Iflowsetup -SRM=Flow.exe"
   /  "**Setup64.exe -U -Iflowsetup -SRM=Flow.exe**".
3. Then copy that one you need in **CMD**(as administrator), go to directory **C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\Flow** and hit **Enter**.